# Different behaviour of Django's django.utils.crypto.salted_hmac depending on uwsgi run manually or via service

Tags: django, cryptography, uwsgi

Experiencing a hard to understand  behavior.

I feed `salted_hmac` function with predefined arguments - `key_salt`, `value` and without providing `secret_key`.

When I run this via django command, I get some `key` inside salted_hmac function: `key = hashlib.sha1(key_salt + secret).digest()`.

Same `key` I get, when running this from a django view, run on runserver or from a the same django view, while being run on uWSGI, which has been launched directly from terminal.

On the other hand, when I run uWSGI via a service - the `key` in `salted_hmac` function differs.

The only difference between those runs is the way it's run. I use exactly the same .ini file with uWSGI configuration.

My guess would be that secret keys differ between running this function from terminal / from service, but when I print `secret_key` inside salted_hmac function - it's the same key...

Moreover, if I hardcode `secret_key` param when calling `salted_hmac` function - , I get the same `key` generated in `salted_hmac`, regardless of it's running directly from terminal or from a view on uWSGI, running from a service...

Comment: Show us the exact code that you are running... it seems highly likely that the issue is with how you are calling the function.